# clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

Tags: objective-c

I try to archive my app for testing within my team and get the following error:

clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

The error occurs on random files within my project. The log states the following:

```
CompileC /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/YNotification+CoreDataProperties.o YNotification+CoreDataProperties.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.4 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Testballon1-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Testballon1-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Testballon1-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Testballon1-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google/Google -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -I/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -I/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google/Google -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GGLInstanceID -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/Google/Google -isystem -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -isystem /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleCloudMessaging -isystem -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/YNotification+CoreDataProperties.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/YNotification+CoreDataProperties.dia -c /Users/Clanzett/Documents/Apps/Testballon1/YNotification+CoreDataProperties.m -o /Users/Clanzett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testballon1-ewaxhionniicpbgagakfznwubgdk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Testballon1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Testballon1.build/Release-iphoneos/Testballon1.build/Objects-normal/armv7/YNotification+CoreDataProperties.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have -isystem -isystem ... in the command line, check your Build Settings to see if you can find the problem.

You can search your `XCBuildConfigutation` section of your `.pbxproj` (Everything between `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */` and `/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */`)